# How do I turn a glob::GlobError into an io::Error in Rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust, glob, ownership

I have a [`glob::GlobError`](https://docs.rs/glob/0.2.11/glob/struct.GlobError.html) from the [glob crate](https://docs.rs/glob/0.2.11/glob/index.html). There's an underlying [`io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html) that I need. How do I get it? There's a few methods available, such as this one:

```
fn error(&self) -> &io::Error
```

However, it just returns a reference. I need to own it, since I want to put it into another error struct that requires ownership.

An other options is this:

```
fn cause(&self) -> Option<&std::error::Error>
```

Same problem with the reference, and on top it's the wrong error type.

It it possible to get an `io::Error` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at outdated documentation.

Go to the latest version, there's a [`pub fn into_error(self) -> Error`](https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/struct.GlobError.html).